# Online and Offline map areas in ArcGIS Field Maps

Tags: offline, online, arcgis-field-maps, enterprise

We are using offline map areas and want to solely use offline areas in ArcGIS Field Maps. When the app has data access the option for online maps becomes available. Is there a way to remove the option of online maps so users only see offline map areas?

Answer (score 0):

For both IOS and Android, you should be able to disable network access for Field Maps. By doing so, the app will only show offline areas.

For example, in Android, you can go into the app's permissions and disable network access.